# Ternary operator in CMake's generator expressions

Tags: cmake, ternary-operator

Cmake's [generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) allow me to use logical expressions within certain function calls. For instance, if I want to add the `/MTd` compiler flag in Debug mode, I can say

```
add_compile_options($<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/MTd>)
```

If `CONFIG` equals "Debug", this will call `add_compile_options` with the value "/MTd", otherwise with an empty string.

But usually, I don't want to decide between a value and the empty string, but between two values. In the example above, if `CONFIG` is *not* "Debug", I want to pass `/MT` (without the trailing d). I'd love to have a syntax like this:

```
add_compile_options($<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/MTd:/MT>)
```

Note that the above is **not valid code** according to the CMake specs. The best I have come up with that actually works is this:

```
add_compile_options($<$<CONFIG:Debug>:/MTd>$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Debug>>:/MT>)
```

This seems awfully redundant to me. Is there a shorter, more readable way to decide between two values?

Note: I realize that in this special case, I could write this:

```
add_compile_options(/MT$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:d>)
```

But this seems rather hacky to me and only works in those cases where one option is a substring of the other.

Comment: I don't think it's currently possible (as for CMake version 3.4.1), but there is already a feature request [0015585: Add support for the if / else construct to generator expressions](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=15585) you could support.

Comment: For the moment being you could define a macro, and in fact limit your call to `your_macro(Debug,/MTd,/MT)`

Comment: I provided a macro definition in my answer.

Comment: The `$<IF>` operator was just added with [this commit](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/commit/895f7f16a79428689a263ba5cd9a72647dc8e912).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Note that cmake 3.8 added exactly what you want to generator expressions ...

```
$<IF:?,true-value...,false-value...>
true-value... if ? is 1, false-value... if ? is 0
```

Example usage:

```
target_link_libraries(MyLib PUBLIC
    $<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,cppzmq,cppzmq-static>
    )
```

Where `cppzmq` is shared library used in `Debug` build and `cppzmq-static` is static library used in other case e.g. `Release`

Comment: Nice find! It's documented here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.8/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#id3

Comment: Thanks, but documentation does not give a single example for `$<IF..` construct which was the reason of my confusion.

Comment: @vulcanraven  Indeed the cmake documentation is very short on helpful examples.  Does the example that Dawid Drozd added help you enough?

Comment: @LanceE.T.Compte, wasn't looking _just_ for an example :) I saw a code somewhere of the form `$<IF: $<cond>, trueValue>`, without needing to specify false. I was searching for documentation on `$<IF` construct and couldn't find one. To me, `$<IF` sounds like a very fundamental thing to have as part of documentation in any platform.

Comment: @vulcanraven $<IF ...> is documented here: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html   Omitting the falseValue would substitute an empty string.  I actually do that when adding debug flags, etc.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to find. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a working example, with a macro:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

macro(ternary var boolean value1 value2)
    set(${var} $<${${boolean}}:${value1}>$<$<NOT:${${boolean}}>:${value2}>)
endmacro()

set(mybool 0)
ternary(myvar mybool hello world)

add_custom_target(print
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo ${myvar}
    )
```

Create a `CMakeLists.txt` file and run `cmake . && make print` (generator expressions are only evaluated at build time).

Try changing the value of `mybool` to `0` or `1` and see what happens.

The following definition also works, and it is clearer:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

macro(ternary var boolean value1 value2)
    if(${boolean})
        set(${var} ${value1})
    else()
        set(${var} ${value2})
    endif()
endmacro()

set(mybool 0)
ternary(myvar mybool hello world)

add_custom_target(print
    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo ${myvar}
    )
```

### TL;DR

`ternary(var boolean value1 value2)`

means, comparing to C/C++:

`int var = boolean ? value1 : value2;`

Comment: Just a hint: I think neither the first (dereferencing the variable's content) nor the second definition (`if` checking the variables content) would work, if `boolean` contains a generator expression.

Comment: @Florian you are right. I've tried to fix it, however, no success. But IMHO it would be nice to have some CMake ternary module or at least an `IIF()`-style function.

Answer (score 0):

Let's make it more explicit:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET myProject PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND cd \"D:/projects/$<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,Debug,Release>\"
    COMMAND call prebuild.bat)
```

Then in generated Visual Studio Project, in the property window of project "myProject".

When build configuration is "Debug", the evaluation process is:

1. `$<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,Debug,Release>`
2. `$<IF:1,Debug,Release>`
3. `Debug`

[image]

When build configuration is "Release", the evaluation process is:

1. `$<IF:$<CONFIG:Debug>,Debug,Release>`
2. `$<IF:0,Debug,Release>`
3. `Release`

[image]