# CMake use flags for specific configuration in external project

Tags: cmake

I'm using `ExternalProject_Add` to build an external `make`-based project. I'd like to propagate flags according to the current build-configuration.

I basically have to following command:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
        ...
        BUILD_COMMAND make CFLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_???}
        ...
        )
```

and I want to use `CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG` when the project is built in Debug, or whatever the current configuration is. How can that be done? I've tried this, but it doesn't parse:

```
ExternalProject_Add(
        ...
        BUILD_COMMAND make CFLAGS=${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_$<CONFIG>}
        ...
        )
```

Comment: If you use single-configuration build tool, you may obtain current configuration name via `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable. In case of multi-configuration build tool you seems out of luck: generator expressions work only where it is explicitly documented.

Comment: That’s a good start, but the problem is that that gives me e.g. Debug, where I need DEBUG for the variable name.

Comment: A variable's suffix is just an upper-case version of build type. Use `string(TOUPPER)` for this transformation.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a proper solution, but a reasonable compromise. Since the most important thing for us was to use the correct flags in the release build, I'm now checking specifically for that, using [this rather convoluted workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34393562/ternary-operator-in-cmakes-generator-expressions) for the lack of `if-then-else` in generator expressions prior to 3.8:

```
set(default_flags "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g -O2")
set(release_flags "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} ${CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE}")
set(flags $<$<CONFIG:Release>:${release_flags}>$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Release>>:${default_flags}>)

ExternalProject_Add(
    ...
    BUILD_COMMAND make CFLAGS=${flags}
    ...
    )
```